# Adding an existing VMs to the Azure Load Balancer Through ARM templates

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Could anybody please share scripts for adding an existing VMs to the Azure Load Balancer. How can we update the back-end pool of the LB with ARM scripts. 
I have been following this script "https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-2-vms-internal-load-balancer/azuredeploy.json" ,but the above script is for New deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can [see from the template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-2-vms-internal-load-balancer/azuredeploy.json#L142) its not actually updating the backend pool, it only creates it. You attach a vm [by adding a loadBalancerBackendAddressPools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-2-vms-internal-load-balancer/azuredeploy.json#L111) property to the vm nic:

```
"loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
    {
        "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')) , '/backendAddressPools/BackendPool1')]"
    }
]
```

Comment: The above script is creating VMs and load balancer in  the same script. I have already created 3 VMs with different ARM template with an availability set. Now i want to add those VMs to the backend pool of the LB while creating it.

Comment: read the answer, it doesnt change anything. you just need to link the NIC to the LB

Comment: Hello,
i am trying to add NIC to the backendpool of LB with this code ""backendAddressPool":
{
"id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('Nic')), '/backendAddressPools/BackendPool1')]"} 
" And i am getting this error message "message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestFormat",
    "message": "Cannot parse the request.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidJsonReferenceFormat",
        "message": "Reference Id /subscriptions/Sub-id/resourceGroups/AVtest/providers/
Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/MyVM01-NIC1/backendAddressPoo.

Comment: /BackendPool1 is not formatted correctly. The Id 
is expected to reference resources of type loadBalancers/backendAddressPools. Path 
properties.loadBalancingRules[0].properties.backendAddressPool."

Comment: Could you please help me on the script?

Comment: resourceId you are supposed to pass, srsly read the answer, it got everything you need. I've even linked relevant pieces of code in the example template, what do you not understand?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you,

i am passing this " "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('Nic') to add my VM to the backend pool of the LB, But i am getting the above error.
Could you please let me know how to get Resource ID for a NIC of the VM

Comment: dude, read the answer ;) you dont touch the load balancer, you configure the NIC

Comment: Got it Thank you very much